# How to use NaN semantics functionality in Apache spark 1.5? what kind data we need to insert in table?

Tags: semantics, nan

what is NaN semantics in Apache spark 1.5, how we can use for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're referring to Spark SQL's NaN semantics, they are descried in the SQL Programming Guide: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/sql-programming-guide.html#nan-semantics

For more detailed information, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9076, an umbrella JIRA which links to several of the patches that implement these semantics.

Comment: Hi Josh,thanks for your answer..correct me if i am wrong ..in table i can put data like 0 or any other number and  i should write one program and  need to check the value for example 0/0 what vallue will return, can i check this with running simple query without writing any program ...can you give me one example with simple query? or what kind of data i can put in table which is created with double and float datatype...one example will be great help for me...thanks